Border under selected element
When I select one element, I know that the bottom border shouldn't be displayed under that one. It should look like in this image CSS Border.
Code:
CSS:
import styled, {css} from "styled-components";
export const NavBarNotificationWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: self-start;
    font-size: 16px;
    gap: 20px;
    color: #6C6C6C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  
`;

export const NavBarItem = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    ${(props) =>
        props.isSelected &&
        css`
            border-left: 2px solid #090A72; 
            border-right: 2px solid #090A72; 
            border-top: 2px solid #090A72; 
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            
         
            
        `}
    
`;

export const NavBarItemContent = styled.div`
    padding: 10px;

`;


React:
 const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId\] = useState(null);

    const handleNavBarItem = (id) => {
        setSelectedItemId(id === selectedItemId ? null : id);
    };
    
    return (
        <NavBarNotificationWrapper>
            {testText.map((el) => (
                <NavBarItem
                    key={el.id}
                    isSelected={el.id === selectedItemId}
                    onClick={() => handleNavBarItem(el.id)}
                >
                <NavBarItemContent>{el.name}</NavBarItemContent>
                </NavBarItem>
            ))}
        </NavBarNotificationWrapper>
    );

};

I tried using pseudo-selectors and other methods, but it didn't work.

Can you edit the CSS? Set the bottom border color to transparent.

don't set border-bottom on NavBarNotificationWrapper. Instead set it on NavBarItem and based on selectedItemId you can add a class that removes the border
